# Updating product description in Magento 2 via REST

Tags: rest, magento2

I'm exporting product data to a Magento 2 shop via the REST API. Creating products work perfectly, but when I update an existing product the `description` and `short_description` don't get updated.

The data:

```
{
  sku: 'LEDSL302',
  price: 7,
  name: 'LEDguardian®',
  attribute_set_id: 4,
  type_id: 'simple',
  custom_attributes: [
    { attribute_code: 'description', value: 'foo' },
    { attribute_code: 'short_description', value: 'bar' }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @geon, did you solve the problem? I am with the same issue. If you found the solution answer your won question. Cheers

Comment: @luigibertaco Yes, I did. Check the answer I posted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out Magento for some reason was inconsistent in what store ID it used. Explicitly setting the store in the request URL fixed it.

Bad url: `/index.php/rest/all/V1/products/`

Good url: `/index.php/rest/default/V1/products/`

See? `all` was supposed to affect a product globally, but didn't work. Selecting the default (and in my case, ONLY) store with `default` instead fixed the problem.